# GTM Ecommerce tracking script

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, code-snippets, enhanced-ecommerce

I have to turn this code into a script compatible with **Google Tag Manager**, but I don't know how to do it.
I've tried to make some changes but I don't even understand what programming language this is.
I'm desperate, I couldn't find anything like it on the Internet.
Thank you in advance to those who will help me solve this problem.

#### Unknown Code:

```
    <!-- Google Enhanced Ecommerce Analytics -->

    {% if group.analytics != ''%}
        {% if request.path.2 == 'transfer' or request.path.2 == 'mark' or request.path.2 == 'findomestic' %}
            {% set affiliation_title = group.title|replace({' ':'-'}) %}
            {% set order = getOrderById(request.path.3) %}
            <script type="text/javascript" data-pagespeed-no-defer>
                ga('require', 'ecommerce');
                ga('ecommerce:clear');
                {% for k,item in order.cart.items %}
                    {% set product_handler = ( k | split('#|#') ) %}
                    {% set product_object = getItem(product_handler.0) %}
                    {% set category_id = product_object.categoryUID[0] %}
                    {% set category_path = '' %}
                    {% if category_id > 0 %}
                        {% set list = getCategoryList(category_id) %}
                        {% for i,cat in list %}
                            {% if i == 0 %}
                                {% set category_path = '' ~ cat.name %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% set category_path = category_path ~ '/' ~ cat.name %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}
                    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
                        'id': '{{order.orderID}}',
                        'name': {{ item.title | json_encode | raw }},
                        'sku': {{ item.sku | json_encode | raw}},
                        'category': {{ category_path | json_encode | raw }},
                        'price': '{{ item.price | replace({',':'.'}) }}',
                        'quantity': '{{ item.count }}',
                        'currency': '{{group.currency}}'
                    });
                {% endfor %}
                ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
                  'id': '{{order.orderID}}',                    
                  'affiliation': '{{affiliation_title}}',   
                  'revenue': '{{order.total| replace({',':'.'})}}',
                  'currency': '{{group.currency}}'
                });
                ga('ecommerce:send');
            </script>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

#### GTM code example:

```js
<script>
var dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
dataLayer.push({
  'transactionId': '03142',
  'transactionProducts': [{
  'sku': 'AA1132544',
  'name': 'T-Shirt',
  'category': 'Apparel',
  'price': 11.99,
  'quantity': 1
  },{
  'sku': 'AA1243544',
  'name': 'Socks',
  'category': 'Apparel',
  'price': 9.99,
  'quantity': 2
  }]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the unknown code is django, see examples here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/